Issue in ODBC Connection
I'm trying to connect ODBC from Pentaho. For this I created ODBC connection from SYSTEM level. But when I tried to connect from PENTAHO ODBC always its taking port 1521.
How and where to change the port? I tested from ODBC driver itself. Based on the TNS name the connection is working fine.
